# Qatar Airways QR161, Jan 10th 2023 - can I expect an official and public report?

Tags: incidents

Danish media is currently reporting about an incident on January 10th 2023 with Qatar Airways QR161 from Doha to Copenhagen.

Best source I could find (Aviation Herald):
[Incident: Qatar B788 at Doha on Jan 10th 2023, steep descent after takeoff](https://avherald.com/h?article=504d75c7)

**Essential excerpts:**

- *had climbed to about 1800 feet when the aircraft entered a steep descent losing 1000 feet within 24 seconds*
- *the captain took control of the aircraft and recovered about 800 feet above water.*
- *The occurrence was not reported to the authorities and only came to light later.*

**Official/ public incident report?**

By coincidence I started watching [Mentour Pilot](https://www.youtube.com/@MentourPilot) on YouTube recently, and he often walks through so called "final reports" for various incidents. I wonder if such reports are always made public so that I can expect to be able to read a report on this incidence sooner or later?

Comment: 1000' of elevation in 24 seconds is 2500 FPM descent. Is that really a "steep descent"? Seems to me that this is within normal descent rates for a commercial airliner. Granted, it's usually not good to do that on take-off, when you should be ascending, but it doesn't seem like it would have caused any significant stress to the aircraft. Maybe that's why it wasn't reported "until later".

Comment: @FreeMan 2500 fpm down _at that altitude_ and in that phase of flight is a big deal indeed. The characterization doesn't seem unfair to me. Not to mention that a transport category aircraft _ever_ descending to 800 feet (except during a stabilized approach to a runway) is cause for concern, regardless of descent rate or airframe stress.

Comment: Thanks, @TypeIA. I did note that it wasn't good, especially on take off. I guess that's a fair assessment.

Comment: And now a very similar incident on United https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/united-777-plunge-takeoff-hawaii/index.html Eerily similar - 2200 ft to 775 ft (vs. 1800 to 800), rest of the flight went normally and flew to planned destination.

Comment: That is United Flight 1722. Both that one and this one (Qatar Airways QR161) are now [covered by *blancolirio*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1B9mQQnZg_8&t=7m20s) (at 07 min 20 secs for the latter (for this question)).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In general, all ICAO member states must investigate **accidents** and are recommended to investigate **serious incidents** according to ICAO Annex 13:

> 5.1 The State of Occurrence shall institute an investigation into the circumstances of the accident and be
> responsible for the conduct of the investigation [...]
>
> 5.1.1 Recommendation.— The State of Occurrence should institute an investigation into the circumstances of a
> serious incident.

<sup>([ICAO Annex 13](https://www.emsa.europa.eu/retro/Docs/marine_casualties/annex_13.pdf) CHAPTER 5. INVESTIGATION)</sup>

The difference between an accident, a serious incident and an incident is also defined in Annex 13:

> ***Accident.*** An occurrence associated with the operation of an aircraft which takes place between the time any person boards the
> aircraft with the intention of flight until such time as all such persons have disembarked, in which:
> a) a person is fatally or seriously injured [...]
> b) the aircraft sustains damage or structural failure [...]
> c) the aircraft is missing or is completely inaccessible.
>
> ***Incident.*** An occurrence, other than an accident, associated with the operation of an aircraft which affects or could affect the
> safety of operation.
>
> ***Serious incident.*** An incident involving circumstances indicating that an accident nearly occurred.

<sup>([ICAO Annex 13](https://www.emsa.europa.eu/retro/Docs/marine_casualties/annex_13.pdf) CHAPTER 1. DEFINITIONS)</sup>

The question is now whether or not the incident you linked to will be classified as serious (see also Attachment C of Annex 13 for examples). According to the Aviation Herald article, the authorities have been informed, in this case the [Air Accidents & Incidents Investigation](https://www.caa.gov.qa/en-us/About%20CAA/Pages/Air-Accidents-and-Incidents-Investigation-Unit.aspx) unit of the Civil Aviation Authority of Qatar (QAAI). They will decide whether or not to investigate further. They have in the past closed investigations when the incident was no longer considered serious, e.g.

> On Jan 29th 2023 the QAAI informed The Aviation Herald, that following additional information the occurrence was re-categorized an incident, the investigation was cancelled.

<sup>([AvHerald - Incident: Qatar A320 near Baghdad and Doha on Dec 23rd 2022, return to Doha results in fuel emergency](http://avherald.com/h?article=503b0c0e))</sup>

**If** the QAAI investigates the incident, they will publish the **final report** once the investigation has been completed:

> The State conducting the investigation of an accident or incident shall also make the Final Report publicly available as soon as possible and, if possible, within twelve months.
>
> If the report cannot be made publicly available within twelve months, the State conducting the investigation shall make an interim statement publicly available on each anniversary of the occurrence – detailing the progress of the investigation and any safety issues identified.

<sup>([ICAO FAQ](https://www.icao.int/about-icao/FAQ/Pages/icao-frequently-asked-questions-faq-11.aspx): What are a State’s reporting obligations during and after an aircraft accident investigation?)</sup>